# replace specific div with some content with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In my HTML code, I have something like the following:

```
<div class="placeholderAccordion">
    <h4>title goes here</h4>
    <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

With JavaScript, I try to use `.replace()` to replace the div and everything inside it with something else, but I can't make it work. I'm still new to regex... Does anybody have a regex to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it is very simple:

```
$('.placeholderAccordion h4').html('title replaced.');
$('.placeholderAccordion p').html('content replaced.');
```

Try it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z60zdav/)